# MS Access: Attachment type symbol shows black backround

Tags: ms-access, background, format, icons, attachment

I have a small database project where users can attach files to records. Mostly pdf and word docs. I am using the attachment type fields that access provides because I want to get more familiar with them. I have a continuous form that shows the attachment field using the `Picture/Symbol` view option. Most of the time, but strangely not always, the attachment symbol shows this black background behind its symbol. The black background does not cover the whole field but rather only the picture for the attachment type (Word, PDF etc.). The field itself is set to transparent, which is neccesary for my row highlighting to work. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it a bug? Some way to fix it? It had worked when I had first set it up but upon restarting my computer and reopening the project they turned black and are now stuck that way. I removed them later for some reason and re-did the whole thing, upon which it seemingly worked but after restarting it went black again. There is no difference between using the view settings `Picture/Symbol` and `Symbol`.

*Visual Aid:*

[image: Black Backgrounds]

---

***Update 1:***

The black backgrounds are seemingly random. I set the view option to `Paperclip`, restarted access, then set them to `Picture/Symbol` again and now I get this:

[image: Partially black backgrounds]

Closing and opening the file appears to turn the backgrounds black. Changing the view type back and forth inbetween can fix some, but not always.... I'm really not sure what's going on.

---

***Update 2:***

The issue is seemingly not affected by transparancy settings. Changing the Background color of the field has no impact either. The issue also persists when making a new form from scratch and adding the `Attachment` type field to it. It also carries over from one pc to another, so unless both have the same issue in their windows installation I don't think that is the root cause either. Compress & Repair did not help. I am only using one attached file per record.

[image: Pink Background as visual aid]

---

***Update 3:***

I have had no luck consistently reproducing the issue. Most of the time, about 80% of it I am estimating, the issue persists. Some days, when launching access, the issue is resolved partially for either the word icon, or the pdf icon. On some days the issue is resolved for all icons as in the picture below. Almost always, after closing and opening access, the issue will immediately reappear for all icons. Closing and opening the form only and keeping the file open is fine, the issue stays resolved. Really not sure how to go about this.

[image: Issue temporarily resolved after restart]

---

My Access version:

***Version 2205 Build 16.0.15225.20028***

My Windows install:

***Microsoft Windows 10 Pro***

***10.0.19044 Build 19044***

Comment: I'm confused -- does the image have a transparent background?  (What is the filetype?)

Comment: Thinking more about this, I remember once fighting with the same problem, related to the fact that, internally, Access stores [most] images as bitmaps (BMP).  At the time I was probably using PNG images since they support transparency ("alpha").... however BMP does not.  I suspect [this MSDN answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/ea830687-6574-42ce-b004-8874b702bdf1/png-transparency-is-not-preserved-in-access-report-print-preview#d1a8a84e-5393-47ba-b5b3-82197b990205) (and the link within, "Make an image transparent") will be helpful to you.

Comment: ahh sry, misread. Filetype for DATEI is `Attachment`. The Image should have a transparent background, since that is how it appeared the first time I applied it to the form. But I am not 100% on this since they are auto-applied by access itself and not by me manually. No idea where it stores them.

Comment: @ashleedawg, Embedded files are not images - they are other file types such as doc and pdf that cannot be displayed in Image control, only represented by an icon. I cannot replicate the issue in Access 2010.

Comment: @June7 : Did you save the file, reboot and open it back up again? That's when it started for me.

Comment: Tried that. No change. I can set control's BackColor to show dark background.

Comment: Yes. The first time the issue popped up was after rebooting. Not sure if it makes a difference. Just an idea. I can change BackColor to Black, but that looks pretty ugly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, updated to windows 11 and the issue is solved. No idea what was wrong exactly but it turns out it was related to the windows install. So, some kind of a bug in Win 10 is my guess, since it was happening on two different machines both running win 10.